# Automated file import with SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am very new to **SSIS** and its capabilities. I am busy building a new project that will upload files to a database. The problem I am facing is that files and tables differentiate from one another.

So what was done is I created a table that will map each file's columns to the specific table's column the data needs to be stored in, in a separate table. I want the user to manage this part when they receive a new file or the file layout changes some how.

As far as I know about **SSIS** is that you can map each file to a table and it can be scheduled as task.

My question is will **SSIS** be able to handle this or should I handle this process in code?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it all depends on the amount of data that would be imported into your SQL server, for large data sets (Normally 10000+ Rows) it becomes a necessity to utilize the SSIS as you would receive performance gains in your application. [Here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/on-the-fringe/2013/08/25/creating-and-executing-an-ssis-package-programmatically/) is a simple example of creating a SSIS package using code. For smaller data operations I would suggest using a combination of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx). Or to Create a dynamic table on your SQL server based on the file format, look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29045/Import-Excel-files-to-SQL-Server-dynamically)

Answer (score 2):

SSIS can be very picky about file formats, so if the files are completely different, then it probably isnt the tool for the job. For flat files, SSIS requires the ordering of columns to be the same.

If you know that your files will only ever arrive in one of 5 formats (for example), it wouldn't be much trouble to write 5 packages to import them. If any new file could have a totally different schema, I dont think SSIS would be the right tool for the job.